# facebook app, continuous redirect?

Tags: facebook, redirect, fbml

Does anybody have any idea why my facebook app keeps redirecting in a loop?

```
http://apps.facebook.com/freemoviedb/
```

Comment: post some of the code to be able to detect some errors, if any

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If u are using $facebook->requireLogin(); with teh old REST-API... DONT!
It's broken from time to time. You should use the redirect version:

Sample here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem because my server didn't support cURL requests for external servers - check cURL support.